# Check if a sentence contains only alphabetic letter in php

Tags: php

I have a sentence

> ex: Hello word am new to php.

I want to check wether the whole sentence including the white spaces are alphabets. I have tried to used `ctype_alpha` and `regex - preg_match("/^[a-z]+$/i",$val)` but not working for me so far.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allow at least white space in your regex

```
preg_match("/^[a-z ]+$/i",$val)
```